# AWS EC2 Lost Data after attaching volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm sort of new to AWS EC2 instances, but also comfortable.

**16.04 Ubuntu Linux ec2 instance**

I attempted to attach an extra harddrive volume to an existing ec2 instance. The initial default volume of 8 gigs was not enough to satisfy my needs.

I created the new 500gig volume and attached it to my instance, however it became the boot/root volume, so I detached and modified volume to a different device name `/dev/sdf` and reattached it keeping the instance's `/dev/sda1` drive I *had* data on.

Upon restarting, the data in my initial `/dev/sda1` was reverted back to it's initial snapshot data when the volume was created ( AMI image ), instead of still holding the data that was on it - which is what I was expecting it to do.

Is there anything I can do get that data back? Where is it? No popup or warning said that any data was going to be erased to the volume's initial snapshot and my backup couldn't catch it before hand. The `/dev/sda1` was never detached or touched in this process, but the data is gone.

What happened? Where is my data?

Comment: did you mount the 500 GB volume?

Comment: @AWSPS Yes, I did

Comment: There is no way the data can be lost, you didn't delete the volumes based on your question

Comment: @AWSPS I think I may have mounted incorrectly, both of the drive volumes have the same UUID and label and both appear to contain the same files

Comment: I just don't know

Comment: you created the volume manually, the UUID won't be the same

Comment: @AWSPS Is there anyway we can chat, the initial 8 gigabyte `/dev/sda` shows that it doesn't have a mount point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205113/discussion-between-zac-and-aws-ps).